# What is the cost of increasing the CU above 200k

Tags: solana-program, transactions, cpi

I am making some heavy CPI calls and have increased the compute unit above 200k. Looking at the explorer I did not see any considerable change in how much it costs to do this.

Is there a table or how much does it cost to increase the compute unit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, the tx fee is a fixed fee per tx, the only modifications to the fee are the number of signatures and the number of signatures in the last block:

(https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/master/sdk/program/src/fee_calculator.rs)

Noting that the number of lamports per signature is almost always the floor/minimum value (`5_000`) on mainnet/devnet.

At some point in the future, there will probably be an upgrade that adds a charge per CU used to the tx fee calculation.